# How do I get this struct to work with c#?

Tags: c#, struct

I made a similar program the other day and I was able to use a Struct with no issues whatsoever. I have my struct in a separate file and on my form button click event I am declaring an instance of it and then trying to access the fields to set there values.

```
    public struct PStruct
{
    string Name;
    object Value;
    int Size;
    SqlDbType DataType;
}
```

On my button click I can only get as far as:

```
    PStruct theStruct = new PStruct();
    theStruct.
```

Comment: Your struct should be a class

Answer (score 1):

Make the fields public.

```cs
public struct PStruct
{
    public string Name;
    public object Value;
    public int Size;
    public SqlDbType DataType;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your properties need to be made public to be available to other files. Interfaces and other structures in C# work in a similar fashion where they are private unless specified to be public.

```
public struct PStruct
{
    public string Name;
    public object Value;
    public  int Size;
    public SqlDbType DataType;
}
```